# How to create a login system using mongodb through the REST API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, vue.js, authentication

I keep getting an error when I run this code which says await is only valid in async function. I tried to fix it, but I think I'm putting the code in the wrong place because it's not working, I keep getting the same error message.

Login Client Side:

```
<script>
const logindetails = new Vue({
el: '#logindetails',
data: {

    email: "",
    password: "",

},

methods: {
    login: function (e) {

      const body = { email, password };

        const response = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:3000/authentication/login".then(async response => {
            console.log("success");
          }),
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json"
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(body)

          },

        );
    }}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your *login* function async.

```js
methods: {
    login: async function (e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your login function async -

```
methods: {
login: async function() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Madhu nice seeing you here again. Ok so Jakub is correct that you should put the async behind the function. Also, Remember that .then and await do the same things , so you either use one or the other. In this case, what you want to do is this

```
const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3000/authentication/login", 
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json"
        },

        body: JSON.stringify(body)

      }

    );
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for taking your time to help. I'm getting an error which says Error-in v-on handler (promise/async) what does this mean?

Comment: so this error usually appears when the base url is not correct so in this case "http://localhost:3000/authentication/login" . What port number is your front-end running on?

Comment: Oh ok. It is running on port 3000

Comment: what endpoint are you trying to hit in your restful api? If it is not exactly /authentication/login then it shouldn't work

Comment: Yes I changed it to /students but it's not working. I also changed it on the back-end code.

Comment: It seems this is a separate question. Can you post this problem with the front and back end code?

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you.